# Why isn't this incorrect?

Tags: sentence, syntactic-analysis

> Farmers **who grow** major crops such as corn, rice and wheat,
>   **aware** that new developments in agriculture production can result in millions of dollars in additional revenue, **switching to** newer,
>   **more efficient** technologies. **NO ERROR?**

For the question above I was stumped at the fact of how **aware** can be correct, although, I do see another error at the **switching to** part too.

Anyway, why is **aware** correct and shouldn't it be changed to **are aware**?

Comment: That sentence no verb.

Comment: It looks OK to me except for a missing **are** before *switching*.

Comment: You need to give the sentence a verb. The obvious choices for a verb are *are aware* or *are switching*. If you change it to *are aware*, then the clause *switching to newer ...* isn't connected properly to the rest of the sentence (although the first part is fine).

Comment: Yeah, the only thing that's missing is the "are" before "switching... It's a pretty convoluted sentence but it makes sense except for the missing verb.

Comment: @JimMack But why is **aware** correct though? I checked and **aware** is correct.

Comment: This is apparently an SAT prep question of some sort, not something the OP has written.

Comment: Yes, it is an SAT prep question.

Comment: @Asker123 - "aware" is correct because it is clearly implied that it is the farmers who are aware.  In essence, the first part of the sentence is "Farmers who grow major crops such as corn, rice and wheat, [being] aware that new developments..."

Comment: @WadCheber In that case, as Peter Shor points out, there needs to be an *are* in front of *switching*.

Comment: @WS2 - Agreed.  I was limiting my response to the first half of the sentence.

Comment: It *is* incorrect, but not because of how "aware" is handled, since that's just an adjective phrase modifying "farmers".

Answer (score 2):

The "aware" is fine because it's the beginning of a non-essential clause.  The simplest version of the sentence is:

> Farmers **are** switching to newer, more efficient technologies.

So, to simplify it a bit less (still ignoring the type of farmer being discussed) the phrase would be:

> Farmers, aware that new developments in agriculture production can result in millions of dollars in additional revenue, **are** switching to newer, more efficient technologies.

I hope this makes it clearer why no verb is necessary here. Yes, the description of the farmers makes it a bit more complex, but that's part of what they're testing on the SAT.  So, now if we add back in the farmer description, it should read more clearly:

> Farmers who grow major crops such as corn, rice and wheat, aware that new developments in agriculture production can result in millions of dollars in additional revenue, **are** switching to newer, more efficient technologies.

---

So, what if we try to "fix" the non-essential clause?

Let's start by ignoring the actual end of the sentence:

> Farmers who grow major crops such as corn, rice and wheat, aware that new developments in agriculture production can result in millions of dollars in additional revenue.

So, in this case, we need to add a verb:

> Farmers who grow major crops such as corn, rice and wheat, **are** aware that new developments in agriculture production can result in millions of dollars in additional revenue.

But now we have to remove a comma, which means we're making **two** changes to the sentence, rather than one... and we still have this chunk to add to the end:

> Farmers who grow major crops such as corn, rice and wheat **are** aware that new developments in agriculture production can result in millions of dollars in additional revenue, **switching to newer, more efficient technologies.**

In order for this final part to make sense, we've got to add a lot of words:

> Farmers who grow major crops such as corn, rice and wheat **are** aware that new developments in agriculture production can result in millions of dollars in additional revenue, **so they are** switching to newer, more efficient technologies.

So, now the sentence makes sense but we've had to make a bunch of changes... which isn't a possible solution to the question. So this can't be the "correct" path.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking that but I wanted to fix a non-essential clause. I guess I shouldn't do that.

Comment: If you "fix" the non-essential clause, you're left with a very confusing sentence. I'll try to show that in an edit.

Comment: I think you're over-thinking it.

Comment: @HotLicks Not really. If you're working on an SAT, excluding answers is actually a really good way of figuring out which answer is correct.

Comment: "Over-thinking" is completely rewriting the sentence when it's merely missing the word "are".

Comment: @HotLicks The question is "Why is "Aware" correct?". I'm explaining why "aware" is  correct.